Paddle overlay checkout is not working for sandbox
I'm trying to set up Paddle checkout overlay in my react app. It's working normally when I use the live client-side token and price ID, but when I change it to the sandbox test token it doesn't work and I get a popup saying to contact support.
const ProfilePage = () => {
 const { user, logout } = useUser();
 const location = useLocation();
 const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
 const [paddle, setPaddle] = useState(null);

 useEffect(() => {
  if (location.state && location.state.fromSignup) {
    triggerWelcomePopup();
  }
 }, [location.state]);

const triggerWelcomePopup = () => {
  setShowPopup(true);
};

 useEffect(() => {
   initializePaddle({
     token: "test_**********",
     environment: "sandbox",
     checkout: {
      settings: {
       displayMode: "overlay",
       theme: "light",
       locale: "en",
      },
     },
   }).then((paddleInstance) => {
      console.log("paddleInstance", paddleInstance.PricePreview);
      if (paddleInstance) {
        setPaddle(paddleInstance);
      }
    });
   }, []);

  const openPaddleCheckout = () => {
    paddle?.Checkout.open({
    disableQuantity: true,
    email: "email@email.com",
    items: [
     {
      priceId: "pri_*************",
     },
   ],
   eventCallback: async (data) => {
    if (data.name == "checkout.completed") {
      console.log("hewww");
    }
  },
 });
};

I tried adding this in the index.html file but it also didn't work
    <script src="https://sandbox-cdn.paddle.com/paddle/v2/paddle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Paddle.Setup({ vendor: ***** });
      Paddle.Environment.set("sandbox");
    </script>

I would appreciate it if someone could provide me with a solution if they faced the same issue, I checked again if the live token works and it work
I also tried contacting paddle support but its been 4 days and they didn't answer they don't have the best support
